# How to extract jmeter responses into variables?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I would like to store some responses as variables and use them later in my test. I tried using the following in a post processor beanshell:

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.put("memID", response);
```

However I find that I am getting "stdout:" and "stderr" stored in the variable as well. How can I store just the response without these and the extra spaces?

Edit: response example below-

```
stdout:
      4281


stderr:
```

I need only the number 4281 from this response.

Comment: Can you add the response you get and what you need to extract from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter supports Perl5-style regular expressions, according to [Regular expressions in Perl](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

> **\d** matches any digit character, equiv. to [0-9]
>
> **+**     match 1 or more times

So your Regular Expression should be as simple as just `(\d+)`

Demo:

[image: Regex Demo]

See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex) manual chapter for more information.

Also be aware that you can test your regular expressions agains real response in real time using "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener like in above image. Check out [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more troubleshooting techniques.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `regular expression` to capture anything from response, save it into variable in a TextBox named as `Reference Name`.follow below snapshot as an example.

[image]
from above example you can use the total_quantity any where in your script.

> like this --> ${total_quantity}

Comment: I tried this and now I only get null values in the variable. The response I get is always a number from 3-8 digits long, along with "stdout:" , "stderr:" and some spaces which I need to strip out of it to use the variable.

Comment: try this regex "ResponseValue":[ ]*(\s*\d*)[ ]*

Comment: I have tried that now, and I'm still getting all null values unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your boundaries and that the regular expression you are using is capturing what you want.

A great tool to help you is: https://regex101.com/

Enjoy,

Roland